# Slowness of a Netlogo code line that disappears after pausing the simulation

Tags: netlogo

My Netlogo code is running fast in the first hundreds of ticks and then the speed decreases progressively after that (each new tick takes more and more time to proceed).

I have narrowed down the problem to this line of code:

```
ask turtles [ 

  (foreach vectorX indexes 
    [
      set minilist ?1
      set minilist map customProcedure minilist  <-- this line
      set vectorX replace-item ?2 vectorX minilist
    ])     
]
```

If this line is commented, the speed does not decrease. It is basically applying a custom procedure to each element of "minilist", and this custom procedure is just a succession of "ifelse" conditions.

An interesting phenomenon is that if I pause my simulation (I click on "Go") and restart it from the same place (I click on "Go" again), I get the original fast speed back. It is as if this line of code consumes a lot of memory but this memory would be reset when I stop the simulation.

Do you know what could be causing this problem?

Comment: I have no idea what might be causing this. If you can reduce it to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'd be interested in investigating further. (Also, what does `customProcedure` do... anything special?)